# Crontab: access to BASH internal variables

Tags: linux, bash, unix, cron

How can I set up my crontab environment in such a way so that it has access to built-in BASH variables such as $HOME, $PWD, $OLDPWD, $USER, $PATH, $PS1, etc., so that scripts that rely on these variables can run in crontab environment? Is this a matter of sourcing some files which I'm not aware of, or are matters slightly more complicated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These variables are always set as expected: HOME, PWD, USER.

If you are scheduling your script like this:

```
0 0 * * * /path/to/script.sh
```

and the first line of the script is `#!/bin/bash` then *probably* it will source `~/.bashrc` but not `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile` when running. Other than that, the variables you mention should work as expected. For example, if you change directories within your script, then `OLDPWD` and `PWD` will be updated. I don't see how `PS1` would be relevant in a script.

On the other hand, if in your `crontab` you want to schedule a single command and you want `.bashrc` to be sourced, then you have to write like this:

```
0 0 * * * . .bashrc; somecmd
# or:
0 0 * * * bash -c somecmd
```

Also keep in mind that although you can set variables in a `crontab`, it works different from variables in a shell script. For example these work:

```
SHELL = /bin/bash
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=~/bin:/usr/bin/:/bin
```

This on the other hand won't do what you expect:

```
PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
```

As explained in `man 5 crontab`, values (anything after the `=`) are not parsed, so `$HOME` and `$PATH` in this example will be taken literally.

Answer (score 0):

try using "The EasyCronjobHandler" http://codecanyon.net/item/the-easycronjobhandler/6296537